# Convert Flex To Adobe Air

Tags: flash, air

Currently have a Flex application but trying to convert it into Adobe Air. I really dont have any experience with using Adobe Air desktop app. Any ideas out there?

Comment: Follow a tutorial on [**how to load a picture**](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&q=as3+load+image+example), then when successful just replace the image URL with the one of your Flex SWF. See if simply loading an SWF into an AIR application solves your "convert" problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to move your Web Flex Application to desktop, I would suggest creating a new Desktop AIR project and copy over your files there. Then you will have to change your main from web tags (i thing you are using  now) to  . There may be some bugs here and there but should be pretty straight forward.

Follow this for [more](http://flex.apache.org/doc-getstarted.html) information